# what is a console in java?

Tags: java, input, console, output

I am new to programming and learning Java.
I was looking at an old code and they used something called a console. When I copy-pasted the code, Java did not read anything called a console. Is a console basically a scanner? I searched online and they said it's for input, so should I just remove all consoles and write scanner there instead?
Scanner as in writing Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
I am using the latest version of Java.
(Yes, this for a game of crazy eights)

This is just a part of the old code :

```
// The "CrazyEights" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
public class CrazyEights
{
    static Console c; // The output console

    static int[] deck, player, computer; // card arrays

    static int pile, suit; // discard pile, current suit (0-3)

    static boolean deckEmpty;

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        // setup console
        c = new Console(30, 100, "Crazy Eights");
        intro(); // splash page, instructions
        char playAgain;
        do
        {
            c.setFont(new Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 14));
            game();
            c.setCursor(30, 32);
            playAgain = c.getChar();
        } while ((playAgain == 'y') || (playAgain == 'Y'));
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific Console you are asking for is in your imports.
There is an import "import hsa.Console" on the top of your code. If you are not familiar with imports, as you say you are new to programming/Java, it signifies that when you write "Console" inside this file ("CrazyEights.java") you are referencing the "Console" defined in "hsa.Console".
Now, since this class is specific to your project, we can't know what it is and does. You will have to open it and see for yourself.

However, with a quick search, you are probably using "[ReadyToProgram](http://compsci.ca/holtsoft/)" IDE for Java by Holtsoft and Associates and that's what the prefix hsa stands for in "hsa.Console".
If you are not using that and just copy-pasted the code expecting it to work, it won't. That import is not in the standard Java library. You will need to find it, download it and add it to your project dependencies. If you did that just to start somewhere with Java and it is not essential to you, I would suggest leaving this block of code and moving somewhere else.